# Recoger valores de EditText

Tags: java, android, edittext

Tengo una pequeña duda en Android.
Supongamos que tengo un EditText, en el cual el usuario introducirá un numero por teclado. Como puedo recoger dicho valor?
A ver, yo se hacerlo como si fuera cadena de texto, que seria entonces donde yo hago esto:

```
private EditText et1;

et1 = (EditText)findviewbyid(R.id.et1);

String texto = et1.getText().toString();
```

Pero no se hacerlo si en lugar de texto fuera un numero, por ejemplo un numero referente a la edad. ¿Como se recogería dicho valor?
Gracias y un saludo!

Comment: Lo que obtienes es un String, si quieres un valor númerico de lo que escribes, usa Integer.parse().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar este para convertirlo a integer o double (ver mas abajo):

```
String texto = et1.getText().toString();
```

Para un número entero, cualquiera de estas 2 formas:

```
int numero = Integer.parseInt(texto);
int numero = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
```

Para decimales:

```
double decimal = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
double decimal = Double.parseDouble(texto);
```

Puedes agregar `.trim()` para omitir espacios en
blanco que pudiera haber antes o despues del número ingresado:

```
int numero = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString().trim());
```

Answer (score 2):

Todo lo que recojas te vendra como un String, lo que debes hacer es hacerle un parse, por ejemplo:

```
Int edad = Integer.parse(et1.getText().toString())
```

Comment: Entonces a ver si lo he entendido. Todo lo que recoja de un EditText viene como un String. Pero si yo lo quiero como numero hay que parsearlo para convertirlo en eso, un numero. Cierto?

Comment: Es correcto, lo mismo pasa con todo los demas tipos, debes hacerle un parse.

Answer (score 1):

Si es un número es el mismo procedimiento, en realidad el método [getText()](http://String%20texto%20=%20et1.getText().toString();) regresa el texto que es desplegado por el `TextView`.

Por lo tanto es indiferente si es un String o un número.

Pero si lo quieres obtener el valor `numerico`,entonces tienes que convertirlo, puedes usar para esto `Integer.parse()` :

```
Int valor = Integer.parse(et1.getText().toString())
```

Como mejor práctica usa el método `trim()` para evitar posibles espacios en el contenido de tu `EditText`:

```
Int valor = Integer.parse(et1.getText().toString().trim())
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo recomiendo que tomes algunas medidas de seguridad al parsear:

```
String sEdad = et1.getText().toString();
Int iEdad = 0;
if("" != sEdad)  iEdad = Integer.parse(sEdad);
```

Con esto evitas un error de conversion en caso de que se llame al metodo parse y el String este vacío